# Deleting from a python array and restoring to previous state

Tags: python, arrays, append, restore

I am writing a program where the program displays a word to the user which is encoded. The program allows the user to enter a character to see if that character is in the encoded word. If the character enters a character, I want to allow them one go at deleting their entry and restoring the original character back to the array.

Here is my code so far -  I have started to develop the part of the program that will append each entered character to a list. My question is how I can revert back to the original character.

```
while Encoded_Team != Team:
    print("\nThe encoded team is", Encoded_Team,"\n")
    Choose = input("Choose a letter in in the encoded team that you would replace: ")
    Replace = input("What letter would you like to replace it with? ")
    array.append(Choose)
    array.append(Replace)
    Encoded_Team = Encoded_Team.replace(Choose, Replace)
    Delete = input("\nWould you like to delete a character - yes or no: ")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Encoded_Team = Encoded_Team.replace(Replace, Choose)`? Or could they be changing to a character that was already in `Encoded_Team`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be easier to handle with a `list`:

```
encoded = list(Encoded_Team)
plaintext = list(Team)
changes = []
while encoded != plaintext:
    print("\nThe encoded team is {0}\n".format("".join(encoded)))
    old = input("Which letter would you like to replace? ")
    indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(encoded) if c == old]
    new = input("What letter would you like to replace it with? ")
    for i in indices:
        encoded[i] = new
    changes.append((old, new, indices))
```

Note the ["list comprehension"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is a short-hand version of the following:

```
indices = []
for i, c in enumerate(encoded):
    if c == old:
        indices.append(i)
```

Now you can easily reverse the operations, even if `choose` was already in `encoded`:

```
for old, new, indices in changes:
    print("Replaced '{0}' with '{1}'".format(old, new))
    undo = "Would you like to undo that change (y/n)? ".lower()
    if undo == "y":
        for i in indices:
            encoded[i] = old
```

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for your time and code - I might be able to use that in my program. My problem is that rather than undoing the last character entered, I need to be able to restore a previous character entered once the entered character has replaced already replaced a character. Will I need to append all entered characters to a list and then restore them to the encoded array? I am a little unsure as to how to code the program after I have appended the characters to a list...

Comment: @user3608028 don't try to post code in the comments; it's very difficult to read! If you want to keep a record, you could store a list with the appropriate data, e.g. `changes = [(old1, new1, [i1, i2, i3]), (old2, new2, [i3, i4]), ...]`

Comment: Thanks Jon for taking the time to edit that. I will give this a try!

Comment: Hi Jon. That code works perfectly (thanks!) and I can use that as part of the program! My only problem is that I wanted to give the user the choice of deleting a previous entry even if they made that entry a few choices before - like they have an option to correct a previous mistake a few goes back in the game once they realise that the encoded word isn't what they expected.

Comment: The line I am not quite understanding is the code that comes after "indices = "

Comment: @user3608028 that is a ["list comprehension"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). I will edit to add the equivalent "naked" `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am going to read up on list comprehension! This has been a big help.

Comment: Hi Jon. Sorry to bother you again. I wanted to make one final adjustment to my code before I start  implementing it into a bigger solution. My issue with the code at the minute is the code for restoring or 'undoing' the replacement characters (swapping). At the minute, the program will repeatedly ask the user do they want to undo each replacement one at a time each loop and after a few replacements have been completed, it will keep asking the user if they want to undo previous changes and list all the previous replacements that they have made - my question is would there be a graceful solution

Comment: A solution where the user could specify what replacement they would like to make rather than being asked if they would like to undo the changes for each replacement (one question at a time).

Comment: @user3608028 yes, of course there is, but there are several different routes so it is too broad a question; for example, you could check whether `old.lower() == 'undo'`, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and list the possible changes if it is and let the user pick which to reverse.

Comment: Thanks Jon. That seems like a viable option. Am trying to build the code - not quite there. Seems to be throwing back some errors.

Comment: @user3608028 that's fine; read the messages, find the bugs, fix the code!

Comment: I am trying, Jon. When I read through your code it makes perfect sense but when I try to extend it and adapt to allow the user to select a replacement pair to restore, I'm getting all muddled up!

Comment: I've given it my best shot! Don't supposed you could throw me a bone?

Comment: @user3608028 well I can't very well guess what you've written. If you're completely stuck, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, I didn't give you much to work with, Jon. I was referring to the code that would fulfil the "old.lower() == 'undo', enumerate" section you proposed.